# htaccess automatically detect domain name

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I made script that automatically create subdomain.

the htaccess working fine,
but the problem is, *i need to manually change domain name when install on new domain*.

I want to automatically detect domain name in htaccess, is that possible?

so when adding in another server or new domain, *no need to change the domain root htaccess again*.

domain root htaccess is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]+)\.mydomain\.com(:80)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com
```

i try to change automatically get from `%{HTTP_HOST}`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]+)\.%{HTTP_HOST}(:80)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.%{HTTP_HOST}
```

the problem is on `%{HTTP_HOST}`,
how to get/match current domain in current url with htaccess?

maybe need to get **domain name as variable**.

Thank you

Comment: Please post an example of the input HTTP request's domain and what it should be redirected to, since what yo uhave now doesn't exactly make sense matching `%{HTTP_HOST}` as a substring of a larger domain which also contains `%{HTTP_HOST]`

Comment: thanks, updated with original htaccess and trying to use {HTTP_HOST}

Comment: @Andy: Post some examples of these sub domain names and what do you want to capture?

Comment: @anubhava: actually i just want make root htacess automatically get domain name as variable so i can use to replace mydomain\.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this `RewriteCond` should work for you:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.([^.]+\.[^.]+)$ [NC]
```

So for ex; with a URL like `http://www.sub.domain.com` it will capture `sub` in `%1` variable and `domain.com` in `%2` variable.

Comment: How to capture domain.com?

Comment: So you want to capture `domain.com` from `www.sub.domain.com` or `sub.domain.com` ?

Comment: Yes,
and also is it possible to capture both `sub` and `domain.com`?
the main purpose is, i will not to manually change domain in htaccess when setup in another domain.
Thanks

Comment: thank you!, Now i can get both var, but when use in regex
to replace this code `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com`
with
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.%1`
not working since regex not read `%1`.. or `%2`

Comment: Yes don't put another condition using `%{HTTP_HOST}` If you explain clearly what you're trying to do with your attempted code in the question then I can suggest something.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39427/discussion-between-andy-and-anubhava)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to anubhava's answer if you need to capture the rest of the url after `domain.com` in `%3` you can use the following `RewriteCond`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?((?!www\.)[^.]+\.)?([^/.]+\.[^/.]+)/?([^/]+)?$ [NC]
```