# Detect the domain name automatically in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to remove www and direct to the non www version of the domain, after some research I found that these two lines below will do the job:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

However, When I add the above two lines to my current .htaccess file below, do I need to change the domain.com bit to the website domain? if so, how can I change it so it knows the domain name by it self? so I don't have to change it manually.

I found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427256/htaccess-automatically-detect-domain-name) with MAYBE an answer to this question, but I just don't know how to implement it I am not really an expert but I know that one mistake and can destroy everything, please help.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php 
ErrorDocument 404 /404 

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 

# remove enter code here.php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops 
# By puting the L-flag here, the request gets redirected immediately 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP 
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L] 

# remove index 
# By puting the L-flag here, the request gets redirected immediately 
# The trailing slash is removed in a next request, so be efficient and 
# dont put it on there at all 
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1 [R=301,L] 

# remove slash if not directory 
# By puting the L-flag here, the request gets redirected immediately 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ 
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301,L] 

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect 
# On some hosts RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f will be true, even if 
# no such file exists. Be safe and add an extra condition 
# There is no point in escaping a dot in a string 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/|\.php)$ 
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to redirect `www.example.com` to `example.com`, you can simply match on `www.`. If you want to redirect every subdomain (which is usually not the case), you can possibly match and try to match if it has two parts. It is usually easier to just alter the `example.com` to be your own domain name. In any case, you should add the rule before any other rule.

```
#Option 1: Only redirect if it begins with www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#Option 2: Redirect all the things! (including thingy.sub.domain.example.com to example.com)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*\.([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tested and they work. Note to OP: 301 is a permanent redirect and cached by the browser, if you want to try different settings, use redirect 302 first and change to 301 when you've got what you want.

Comment: @eis Thanks ;-) Removed the 'untested' message :P

Comment: It worked. however @eis I don't really clearly know what you mean by direct to 302 and then to 301 - I just tasted it using: [This tool](http://www.internetofficer.com/seo-tool/redirect-check/) and it shown the following results:  
`Type of redirect: 301 Moved Permanently
Redirected to: http://loaistudio.com/`

Comment: @Loai at the end of a rewrite rule you see HTTP status code you redirect with. 301 is permanent, 302 is temporary. I meant that while testing you could've used 302 instead of 301 showing here.

Comment: @eis, I don't know if this is allowed, but please would you be able to explain what the last rule does? I really have no idea it starts with `"add .php to access file"`

Comment: 301 is the status code of "Moved permanently". For the final site this is the right code to send to the browser. For testing purposes you should send status code `302` (Moved temporarily) with `[R=302]` or simply `[R]`. A temporary redirect is not cached by the browser, meaning if you change something, you directly see the change. Permanent redirects are (sometimes) cached, meaning that if you make a change, nothing seems to happen because the new url is actually loaded from the browser cache, not from the server.

Comment: The last rule allows you to have a link to `http://example.com/test` and that link will load `/test.php` internally if that page exists. If you have more general questions that you don't want to ask in a 'real' question, consider making a chatroom. That way I don't get notifications from people talking in the comments on my answer, but not about my answer ;-)

Comment: @Sumurai8 how can I create a chatroom? Thank you!

Comment: @Loai You can access chat in general via the StackOverflow dropdown in the top-left, the clicking 'chat'. To start a 1-on-1 conversation with someone, either extend the conversation long enough in the comments until it starts suggesting a chatroom or click someone's name, add `chat.` in front of the url (e.g. [this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2756554/loai) for you) and create a chatroom for you both. I am not sure if the other person receives a notification, so leave an @-message in the comment section with a link to said chat room.