# Remove "WWW" from "{HTTP_HOST}" in htaccess rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I have 3 urls and have ssl certification

1) www.example.com

2) myexample.com

3) otherexample.com

I need to redirect all above three urls to https secure url 
e.g. : when user open any one above url it should redirect to https url.

```
=> when user open www.example.com OR example.com >>> it should redirect to https://www.example.com
=> when user open www.myexample.com OR myexample.com OR https://www.myexample.com >>> it should redirect to https://myexample.com
=> when user open www.otherexample.com OR otherexample.com OR https://www.otherexample.com >>> it should redirect to https://otherexample.com
```

Note : I have ssl certificat for www.example.com,myexample.com(non-www),otherexample.com(non-www)

I need help to solve my problem. also I want to set rules dynamically so in future if I have more url(s) so will not edit .htaccess file. (If possible to remove "www" from {HTTP_HOST} set rules below so It would good for me)

I have set coupule of rules in htaccess but it doesn't work for me.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1 [R=301,L]

#rule for myexample.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www.example.com [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         https://example.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]

#rule for otherexample.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www.otherexample.com [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         https://otherexample.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope it will work for you.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Yes I already set this url but for other url it won't work. When user open www.myexample.com it will redirect to https://www.myexample.com but ssl certificate will give exception. that is the main issues that I want to solve. :)

Comment: This link will be helpful for you for getting dynamic domain or sub domain.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427256/htaccess-automatically-detect-domain-name

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

#redirect any other domain that is not "www.example.com" to "https://"
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?:www\.)?((?!example\.com).+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
#redirect  "www.example.com" to "https://www"
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?:www\.)?((example\.com).+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Comment: your solution is work for me but it just static. I want to make it dynamic.
I don't want to write each url statically.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by dynmic?

Comment: When user open www.myexample.com it will redirect to https://myexample.com but ssl certificate will give exception. that is the main issues that I want to solve. So I need solution like If I open www.myexample.com OR www.otherexample.com It will redirect to https://myexample.com,https://otherexample.com respectivaly

Comment: If above code working for you then this link is helpful for you  create dynamic domain. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427256/htaccess-automatically-detect-domain-name

Comment: @MousamiRoul : can you plz help me to understand this line 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?((?!www\.)[^.]+\.)?([^/.]+\.[^/.]+)/?([^/]+)?$ [NC]